# Mismatched Subprogram Error after Setting DebugLoc in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

I am trying to set the DebugLoc of some instructions in LLVM which I have added some metadata to them in previous passes. However, I get an error during the compilation. For example, here you can see part of the LLVM output:

```
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.value variable and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i8 %361, metadata !42467, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !45649, !metadata_dependent !45650
label %for.body238.preheader.3
i32 (%struct.hmmfile_s*, %struct.plan7_s**)* @read_bin20hmm
!42467 = !DILocalVariable(name: "byte", scope: !42461, file: !179, line: 1316, type: !9)
!42461 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "byteswap", scope: !179, file: !179, line: 1313, type: !42462, isLocal: true, isDefinition: true, scopeLine: 1314, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, isOptimized: true, unit: !178, retainedNodes: !42464)
!45649 = !DILocation(line: 201356, scope: !42421)
!42421 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "read_bin20hmm", scope: !179, file: !179, line: 782, type: !42422, isLocal: true, isDefinition: true, scopeLine: 783, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, isOptimized: true, unit: !178, retainedNodes: !42424)
```

Here you can see part of the first pass that inserts some metadata to instructions:

```cpp
int dependent_counter = 0;
for (auto it = total_dependent_insts.begin(), eit = total_dependent_insts.end(); it != eit; it++)
{
    LLVMContext& CC = (*it)->getContext();
    std::string MDS2 = "some_information#" + (*it)->getParent()->getParent()->getName().str() + "#" + std::to_string(dependent_counter);
    MDNode* NN = MDNode::get(CC, MDString::get(CC, MDS2));
    (*it)->setMetadata("metadata_information", NN);
    dependent_counter++;
}
```

And here you can see part of the code in the second pass that sets the DebugLoc of these instructions in order to add some debug information and then collect them after compilation:

```cpp
for (auto it = inst->dependent_insts.begin(), eit = inst->dependent_insts.end(); eit != it; it++)
{
    if (MDNode* NN = (*it)->getMetadata("metadata_information"))
    {
        if ((*it)->getDebugLoc())
        {
            std::string MDStr = cast<MDString>(NN->getOperand(0))->getString();

            DebugLoc L = DebugLoc::get((unsigned)line, (unsigned)0, (*it)->getParent()->getParent()->getSubprogram());
            line++;

            (*it)->setDebugLoc(L);

            errs() << "Metadata String: " << MDStr << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Also I am doing the same thing (inserting metadata and debug information) for one other set of instructions.

I will appreciate if you could give me a clue how to fix this problem.

Thanks

Comment: The problem was attaching metadata and debug information to `call void @llvm.dbg.value ` instructions.

Comment: Could you please explain the solution a bit more, or possibly even write it as an answer? I'm getting a similar error. Were you attaching the MD and dbg info incorrectly?